# Unparse-able list of IPs in allow_if statement

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8, symfony-security

I have the following security configuration:

```
security:

    # .....

    access_control:
        -
            path: ^/path/to/resource
            allow_if: "request.getClientIp() in %my.ips%"

parameters:
    my.ips:
        - '129.0.0.1'
        - '55.12.99.100'
```

Basically I want to allow/deny based on a list of IPs.

This list of IPs keeps changing/growing/shrinking based on some business rules and based on the environment (test, dev, prod etc.). Which is why I HAVE TO write it like that in the `allow_if` rule. I can't just do something like `ip=X or ip=Y or ip=Z or...`.

Now, this doesn't work. I get an error like:

> A string value must be composed of strings and/or numbers, but found
>   parameter "my.ips" of type array inside string value.

I tried all sorts of combinations e.g.:

```
allow_if: "request.getClientIp() in '%my.ips%'"

allow_if: "request.getClientIp() in ['%my.ips%']"

...
```

and I got the same error.

My suspicion is that this is parsed and interpreted using the Expression-Language component. Therefore, according to the syntax described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/service_container/expression_language.html), I tried it like this as well:

```
allow_if: "request.getClientIp() in parameter('my.ips')"
```

But it again failed with the error:

> The function "parameter" does not exist around position 26.

And now I'm kind of stuck. Is there some way I can make this work?

Comment: what about        `- { path: ^/path/to/resource, ips: %my.ips% }`?

Comment: @Matteo Well actually `ips` is used for matching within each `access_control` entry. What I'm trying is to allow/deny access **after** the match is done. But maybe I can use this in my advantage, like setting some `ROLE_FORBIDDEN` role to the user if nothing matches.... Thanks for the idea ;) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I wasn't able to make the expression parse/accept regular parameters, but I was able to work around it.

Here's what I did:

```
security:

    # .....

    access_control:
        -
            path: ^/path/to/resource
            ips: '%my.ips%'
            roles: ['ROLE_MY_ROLE']

        -
            path: ^/path/to/resource
            allow_if: 'false'

parameters:
    my.ips:
        - '129.0.0.1'
        - '55.12.0.0/16'
```

So the way this works is like this:

- try to match the first access-control-entry.
- check if I access the correct path when I have one of these IPs
- if it's true, then check that I have one of these roles
- if my path or my IP does not match, then go to the 2nd entry
- if it's the same path, then deny access (since `allow_if` is always `false`)

So this way the user is obligated to access that route ONLY IF he is coming from a specific IP AND he has one of the allowed roles.

Something interesting that I discovered is that you can use subnets for the list of allowed IPs, which is really cool because it means you can add IP ranges in there as well. Maybe this should be added to the docs, since it's very useful (I'll make a PR on GitHub when I have time).